# JQuery selector using :not

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I would like to use a JQuery selector to select everything inside the form except elements (**and their children**) that have a certatin css class

I tried to use :not selector, but unsuccessfully:

```
$("form:not(.do-not-select)").css("color","red");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u001b2gj/

Could you help me with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
$("form :not(.do-not-select, .do-not-select *)").css("color", "red");
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/u001b2gj/1/).

This passes in a second argument to the negation selector (`.do-not-select *`) and also separates the `:not()` selector from the `<form>` element (as it was you were selecting all forms except those with the class `.do-not-select`), rather than filtering out descendant elements.